# Julia set image rendering ruined by concurrency

Tags: image, go, concurrency, rendering

I have the following code that I am to change into a concurrent program.

```
// Stefan Nilsson 2013-02-27

// This program creates pictures of Julia sets (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set).
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/png"
    "log"
    "math/cmplx"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

type ComplexFunc func(complex128) complex128

var Funcs []ComplexFunc = []ComplexFunc{
    func(z complex128) complex128 { return z*z - 0.61803398875 },
    func(z complex128) complex128 { return z*z + complex(0, 1) },
}

func main() {
    for n, fn := range Funcs {
        err := CreatePng("picture-"+strconv.Itoa(n)+".png", fn, 1024)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}

// CreatePng creates a PNG picture file with a Julia image of size n x n.
func CreatePng(filename string, f ComplexFunc, n int) (err error) {
    file, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()
    err = png.Encode(file, Julia(f, n))
    return
}

// Julia returns an image of size n x n of the Julia set for f.
func Julia(f ComplexFunc, n int) image.Image {
    bounds := image.Rect(-n/2, -n/2, n/2, n/2)
    img := image.NewRGBA(bounds)
    s := float64(n / 4)
    for i := bounds.Min.X; i < bounds.Max.X; i++ {
        for j := bounds.Min.Y; j < bounds.Max.Y; j++ {
            n := Iterate(f, complex(float64(i)/s, float64(j)/s), 256)
            r := uint8(0)
            g := uint8(0)
            b := uint8(n % 32 * 8)
            img.Set(i, j, color.RGBA{r, g, b, 255})
        }
    }
    return img
}

// Iterate sets z_0 = z, and repeatedly computes z_n = f(z_{n-1}), n â‰¥ 1,
// until |z_n| > 2  or n = max and returns this n.
func Iterate(f ComplexFunc, z complex128, max int) (n int) {
    for ; n < max; n++ {
        if real(z)*real(z)+imag(z)*imag(z) > 4 {
            break
        }
        z = f(z)
    }
    return
}
```

I have decided to try and make the `Julia()` function concurrent. So I changed it to:

```
func Julia(f ComplexFunc, n int) image.Image {  
    bounds := image.Rect(-n/2, -n/2, n/2, n/2)  
    img := image.NewRGBA(bounds)                
    s := float64(n / 4)                          
    for i := bounds.Min.X; i < bounds.Max.X; i++ {
        for j := bounds.Min.Y; j < bounds.Max.Y; j++ {
            go func(){
                n := Iterate(f, complex(float64(i)/s, float64(j)/s), 256)
                r := uint8(0)   
                g := uint8(0)   
                b := uint8(n % 32 * 8)  
                img.Set(i, j, color.RGBA{r, g, b, 255}) 
            }()
        }
    }
    return img
```

This change causes the images to look very different. The patterns are essentially the same, but there are a lot of white pixels that were not there before.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. You don't actually wait for your goroutines to finish.
2. You don't pass `i and j` to the goroutine, so they will almost always be the last i and j.

Your function should look something like:

```
func Julia(f ComplexFunc, n int) image.Image {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    bounds := image.Rect(-n/2, -n/2, n/2, n/2)
    img := image.NewRGBA(bounds)
    s := float64(n / 4)
    for i := bounds.Min.X; i < bounds.Max.X; i++ {
        for j := bounds.Min.Y; j < bounds.Max.Y; j++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(i, j int) {
                n := Iterate(f, complex(float64(i)/s, float64(j)/s), 256)
                r := uint8(0)
                g := uint8(0)
                b := uint8(n % 32 * 8)
                img.Set(i, j, color.RGBA{r, g, b, 255})
                wg.Done()
            }(i, j)
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()
    return img
}
```

A bonus tip, when diving into concurrency, it's usually a good idea to try your code with the [race detector](http://blog.golang.org/race-detector).

You *might* have to use a mutex to call `img.Set` but I'm not very sure and I can't test atm.

Comment: mutex wasn't necessary